# Making a view scrollable when keyboard active

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have a view with half a dozen text fields and labels, and a button.

I want it to be that when the keyboard pops up, the view becomes scrollable, so you can scroll the view up and see the bottom half of the fields without having to dismiss the keyboard to get to them.

Just putting it inside a UIScrollView doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the scroll view's `contentSize` to enable scrolling.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks, Ole! That works great when I set it from viewDidLoad.

I guess I could set it programmatically to only enable scrolling when the keyboard is active, hunh? Is there a delegate method I can fire from UILabel to indicate that it just took first responder?